# Does a single threaded application run on only one CPU

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am developing a single threaded application on an 8 CPU machine and when a heavy operation happens the CPU utilization appears like this :

[image]

Does the .NET framework have some facility to divide the work of that single thread (automatically) into the other CPUs ?

Comment: What kind of application is it? console, WPF, WinForms...?

Comment: You do know that CPUs and cores are different right ? I'm guessing you have 1 CPU with 8 cores or 2 CPUs with 4 cores not 8 CPUs.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, Does that matters?

Comment: @thomas its a Winforms application.

Comment: @deathismyfriend yes i know the difference and its a 2 CPU quad core. I was hoping that its obvious. But the questions is kind of simple so I didnt think it was necessary to get into detail.

Comment: @user4032346. vs has this extension, might help you (concurrency visualizer) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx

Comment: @mhs, it does; for instance, WPF does parts of its work on separate threads (binding, rendering...), so in this case the app isn't as "single-threaded" as the OP might think ;)

Answer (score 9):

It's not guaranteed that any single thread will always run on the same core. But it's guaranteed that it will run only on one core **at the same time**. But it can run on one core till context switch, and resume after the context switch on another core. Each time-slice, your thread gets, may be allocated on another core.

Answer (score 5):

> Does a single threaded application run on only one CPU?

As others have noted, not necessarily. However, a given thread will only run on one core *at a time*.

> Does .net framework have some facility to divide the work into the other CPUs?

Yes. .NET has the [`Parallel` class and Parallel LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that you have to divide up the work yourself (into small pieces), and then the .NET framework will handle balancing the work between multiple threads automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Even a process with just one thread may or may not always run that one thread on the same CPU. The *total* CPU utilization for that process cannot exceed 100% of a single core, of course. But that 100% may be spread across as many cores as there are on the machine. So you may see e.g. 50% utilization on two different cores instead of 100% on just one, 25% on four different cores, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET garbage collector will run on another thread, the GUI will if you're doing WinForms/WPF, and the OS will be doing all kinds of work in other threads to help your single-threaded app run faster.

Answer (score 1):

A single threaded application only runs on one core of your CPU so the way it works is when you have multiple CPU's your just getting more cores making your pc more powerful. Your only using one core on all of the CPU's.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old thread, but I arrived here with the same problem, and a different cause/solution.

If you launch your program through the Visual Studio Debugger (VS2012 here), it seems that your threads are bound to a single core. In order to use all the cores available, I had to launch it directly from the executable or from a windows cmd prompt.

May be very specific, but hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

No it will always run in one processor/core, and it might change depending on the scheduler.

You can also use [async and await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx), and they will help with the fluidity of you application.

Have you looked into [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), its a very simple way of creating threads

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Do something that will take a long time
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
});
```

Comment: This is completely besides the point; that's not at all what the OP was asking.

Comment: I love when people down vote something that actually helps, although its not a full answer, the other answers so far simply explain what is the expected behavior (But not down voted), and does not answer at all the 2 questions above.

Comment: The OP is asking if a single-threaded app runs on a single CPU; your answer shows how to run an operation on another thread. I don't see how this answers the OP's question...

Comment: @Oakcool, *who* does it help?  There is no evidence this answer will help the OP.

Comment: @KirkWoll It actually answers both questions. First, a single thread will use one core, unless the processor scheduler changes it. Second, .NET has was of adding "threads" and enable something to be executed across the available core, and Task, is one of them. So contrary to what Thomas said, he is indeed asking if one can run operation on another thread.