# Increase single core CPU usage

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have a simple while loop in C# as follows:

```
private static long a;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    a = 0;
    while (a >= 0)
        a++;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

No matter what I do it wont use more than 60% of a single cpu thread (logical processor), usually around 40%. I want it to use 100% like a C++ loop would.

- I am running in release mode
- I included the writeline so that it's forced to keep the loop and not optimize it out
- Static so it can't automatically create delegate threads (not sure that's possible but just to be sure)
- Using .NET core 2.1 if that matters
- Visual studio 2017 ide/compiler
- Regular console app

And before people ask I know it won't ever use 100% of the overall cpu due to it being single threaded. I want 100% of just one logical processor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Not the same as Does a single threaded application run on only one CPU running exe doesn't help it's not a linq expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a single threaded application run on only one CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557853/does-a-single-threaded-application-run-on-only-one-cpu)

Comment: @mjwills Oh overall is 12% but it's not that useful as dotnet is doing other stuff on other threads to do instruction conversion and memory management.
I'm not saying using a static makes it thread safe but it does make it so the compiler wont automatically separate calls into separate threads as it could be referenced outside of its scope.

Comment: `Oh overall is 12%` So, effectively, it is using 1/8 of your machine's CPU capacity - and you have 8 logical CPUs. So it is, effectively, using an entire logical CPU. Thus, it is likely running over multiple logical CPUs (as per my duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this I get 100% per CPU or 100% per core usage
[image: 1] 
[image: all]

I had to change the counter to long because my PC is too fast for int :-)

I also had to **set affinity to one core** for single tread test, otherwise it keep changing the core.

My guess is your tool is reporting wrong value. If the CPU has turbo mode is can show nonsense values in some SW. Windows regularly show more than 100% cpu frequency in that case.

Another reason can be over heating or some battery saver.

Try is on max performance setting and on different PC

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void BusyDelay()
        {
            long i = 10000000000;
            while (i-- > 0) ;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* use "1" intead of "ProcessorCount" for single thread insted */
            for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount ; i++)
            {
                new Thread(BusyDelay).Start();                
            }                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the affinity can be set by task manager or even in the C# code

Comment: Limiting affinity to single core with realtime priority fixes the issue, thank you.
FYI it was already a long in the original as I had the same issue and turbo calculations have been fixed in task man in windows 10 (7+ if I recall correctly), looks like you are using xp. You never get >100% speeds anymore.

Comment: It on win 7 64 bit with XP theme because XP was the best :-)